# F# async in ASP.NET usage of ThreadPool

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, f#, async-await

I would like to understand `threadpool` usage in `C# vs F# async`. I have a this `F# method in controller in ASP.NET`:

```ml
member x.Get() = 
    async {
        let! res = loadCustomers()
        return res
    } |> Async.StartAsTask
```

I would like to know how much resources, I am using, if everything in async block is running on `ThreadPool` or not. 
In `C# with async/await` it would all run on  `current thread just asynchronously wait for IO completion.`

Documentation of `StartAsTask` function say `"Executes a computation in the thread pool"` so I am affraid that I am using more resources than necessary. I have found `StartImmediate` which starts work on `current thread` but returns just `Unit` and I need `Task for asp.net`.

Comment: Tasks will use fewer resources than Thread, because they make use of the threadpool and may run on different cycles of the same thread. Thread, on the other hand, muscles a separate thread for its own purposes and thus will tend to use more resources over time, since empty cycles cannot be filled with other tasks.

Comment: In general `Async` calls doesn't have any separate `thread` involved. It works on IO completion port, which is hardware based queue. Using a separate Threadpool is surely an extra resource allocated out here, but it is useful in certain cases, especially when we want to not use the synchronization context of the calling thread

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger Maybe title of question was misleading, I have changed Threads to Threadpool. The thing is that C# async / await doesn't use ThreadPool at all, it works on IO completion port. But what I have found about F# is that async block run on threadpool. When I do let! it is just IO and thread is not blocked but it is still using threadpool for the other code in async block.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj My concern is that when I do Async.Start or Async.StartAsTask it moves work to threadpool and involves one more thread. Yes IO is not blocking thread when I do let! but other code in async block in moved to threadpool.

Comment: @Michal `async/await` doesn't use anything, it's syntax for *awaiting* whatever mechanism the framework uses for asynchronous operations. You can await anything with the proper syntax. ASP.NET itself  uses ThreadPool threads, just like Tasks. IO completion ports are used by *specific methods* in coordination with the OS, not `async/await` or Tasks. Each HTTP request is *already* running on a separate ThreadPool thread so starting another one is simply a waste of threads. Unless you *await* for an *already* asynchronous operation, like a DB call started with `ExecuteReaderAsync`

Comment: @Michal long story short, you are doing nothing wrong. ASP.NET MVC recognizes the `async` signature so it knows to release the request thread while you await for the database. This way you *reduce* the number of threads used. When the database returns, ASP.NET will reconstruct the original synchronization context and continue.